# Sum of a Previous Group Summary

Tags: crystal-reports

I have three Groups: `Salesrep` > `Commission Customer` > `Order Number`. My formula totals the commissions at the `Commission customer` level based first on `Order Type`, then on total calculated `Gross Profit`. Paid commission only occurs when the sum of orders is over $50 profit and *not* delivered on a truck.

This works fine in the Commission Customer footer:

`{@sum_slscust_comm}`

```
if {ord.ordtypcod}="P" then
    Sum ({@estslslodcom}, {customer.slscusnum}) 
else if {ord.ordtypcod}="W" then
    Sum ({@estslslodcom}, {customer.slscusnum})
else if Sum ({@slslodgpamt}, {customer.slscusnum}) < -50  then
    Sum ({@estslslodcom}, {customer.slscusnum})
else if Sum ({@slslodgpamt}, {customer.slscusnum}) >= 50 then
    Sum ({@estslslodcom}, {customer.slscusnum})
else
    0
```

But how can I summarize these totals in the Sales Rep footer? This way I can get a total for each rep. I can’t create a sum from a formula that is itself a sum.

I've tried using the summary function, but it tells me the field cannot be summarized. I've tried running totals, and they do not allow me to use the formula. I've tried creating a global number variable, but it does not recognize the formula field as a number and gives me a 'Number is required here" error. What's next?

Comment: Could you show us how are you using the global number variable? [Example Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673897/global-variable-in-crystal-reports)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing Summaries with Running Totals creates much more freedom, including the ability to make Sum Running Totals based on other Sum Running Totals. First and foremost give that a try.

---

In the event that doesn't work, you can also use [Shared Variables](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=304664). You'd basically need 3 new formulas to get that working. To paraphrase:

1) Reset (In Header, suppressed)

```
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar total := 0
```

2) Accum (In Details, suppressed)

```
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar total := total + @sum_val
```

3) Display (In Footer, unsuppressed)

```
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar total ;
total
```